# VPN Works But No Internet For Client

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2012

I have a VPN setup in Windows Server 2012, however they cannot connect to the internet with through the VPN.  They have complete access to the 192.168.1.x and 192.168.92.x network.

The server gets internet from a router at 192.168.1.1

Here's a few pics with details

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTmmq.jpg

If there's any other information you guys need please let me know.  I'm just not sure what I have to do to get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to setup NAT on the Windows 2012 server, that way every time an Internet destined packet from the VPN clients hits the server, it will map their IPs to its the IP of the interface facing the router. In other words, the clients will use the Windows 2012 server as a router, while it translates their IPs to its public facing address and send them to the router. It does the reverse when the packets come from the outside to the VPN clients.

On how to do the configuration, you can follow the link below -

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469812.aspx

Comment: This was a great advice, and probably, you will have to setup your DNS.